# unable to access files with symlink using glob PHP

Tags: php

I created symlink for the directory `/home/pi/app` to `/var/www/html` I can easily display the images in that folder

```
  echo '<img src="/images/test.jpg"/><br />';
```

However I cannot display the list of images in that folder using glob function.

```
$images = glob("/images/*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
 }
```

Is there any way that I can display these images using glob? if i cannot use "glob" is there any functions that i could use?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I've encountered similar issue and in my case I had to add the symlink absolute path in my `open_basedir` value of the Apache virtual.

Answer (score 1):

`glob()` works at the filesystem level. You're providing a web-space url, which doesn't exist on your server.

e.g. you're doing the equivalent of

```
 glob('c:\images\*')
```

but the path you're providing only exists as

```
 glob('c:\inetpub\wwwroot\example.com\images\*');
```

So..

```
glob('/images/*');
```

looks at the top level of your FILE SYSTEM, not the top level of your site's document root. if you had just `glob('images/*')`, then glob would be looking in a subdirectory of whatever directory your script is executing in.

Answer (score 1):

Pathnames in URLs are interpreted relative to the server's document root. You can get that directory in PHP with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

```
$images = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/imags/*.jpg");
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="/images/'.basename($image).'" /><br />';
}
```